# How do I use Java methods correctly?

Tags: java

So, I am SUPER new to Java, but I am trying to make a class-specific program so that I can work on a game within Java. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class boxtype {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] melee = {"Crowbar", "Bowie Knife", "Butterfly Knife", "Knuckleduster"};
    String[] pistol = {"Colt .22", "Magnum .45", "P250", "9mm Pistol"};
    String[] assault = {"AK47", "M4A1", "M16", "SMG", "Mac10", "Minigun (HGE)"};
    String[] shotgunsniper = {"Shotgun", "Benelli S90", "Sniper Rifle"};
    String[] attachments = {"Laser Sight", "Silencer", "Scope", "Auto-target"};
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String xy = scan.nextLine();
    if (xy.equals("spyclass")) {
        spyClass();
    }

}
private static void spyClass(String[] assault, String[] attachments, String[] pistol) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Spy class: ");
    System.out.println("Primary weapon: " + assault[2] + " + " + attachments[2]);
    System.out.println("Secondary weapon: " + pistol[1] + " + " + attachments[2]);
    System.out.println("");
}

}
```

Basically what happens, is Eclipse returns an error saying that "spyClass is not applicable". I'm still researching how to fix, but yeah.

Comment: You have too many curly braces.  Remove the one above the method `spyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

in the call to spyClass you're not passing the parameeters

It should be:

```
if (xy.equals("spyclass")) {
    spyClass(assault, attachments, pistol);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I found a method that _kind of_ works - placing the variables in each method. Thanks for the idea, I'll use that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `spyClass` method expects a bunch of arguments, but you aren't giving it any.  The line that says

```
    spyClass();
```

should perhaps be something like

```
    spyClass(assault, attachments, piston);
```

Answer (score 0):

`spyClass` probably shouldn't be `static` and you need to pass the arguments to it when you call it in your `main` method. `spyClass(assault, attachments, pistol);`